# How do I handle class hierarchies where some subclasses are IDisposable and others are not?

Tags: c#, idisposable

Consider I have a base interface, `IInterface`. I have to classes which implement `IInterface`, `ClassA` and `ClassB`, as such.

```
public interface IInterface
{
}

public class ClassA : IInterface
{
}

public class ClassB : IInterface, IDisposable
{
}
```

Note that `ClassB` is `IDisposable` and `ClassA` is not. Now, if I want to create a `List<IInterface>` which is filled from a factory, how do I handle disposing of the disposable elements? Is it necessary to create a separate `List<IDisposable>` then filter out the list as the objects are constructed (or after construction)? Should I just `IInterface` `IDisposable` with a base abstract class with a default implementation (until C#7 adds default interface implementations)?

I'm not sure what is all of the easiest to utilize and clearest to read in the future. It seems that making all interfaces in which a potential child may be disposable into an `IDisposable` is a potentially annoying practice. Also it requires having bases with empty dispose implementations, which also seems less than ideal.

Comment: Yes, make IInterface:IDisposable. I'd forgo the abstract base class and implement them all explicitly.

Comment: This is an experessivity problem in C# so there's no "ideal" answer. In languages with typeclasses/traits, you can "tack on" an interface definition after the fact, which makes stuff like this cleaner. In C# I think making IInterface:IDisposable is the best middle ground.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check if that instance implements `IDisposable` then call it.
Example:

```
    foreach(var item in listOfClasses)
    {
       var disposableItem = item as IDisposable;

       if(disposableItem != null)
          disposableItem.Dispose();

     ....
    }
```

> Is it necessary to create a separate List then filter out the list as the objects are constructed (or after construction)?

That is not necessary. Just create your list like you initially stated and check for the disposable items like I have shown above.

Does this help?

Comment: You can kill the cast/check, just use `listOfClasses.OfType<IDisposable>()` in the foreach.

Comment: or even shorter by (item as IDisposable)?.Dispose()

Comment: I get that I can iterate over the list and filter by type or cast it, the problem is that if I have to do this with all interfaces of the base interface, why not just make it `IDisposable` in the first place? That also tells others that may have made lists of `IInterface` that they may need to dispose of the objects (though they may not). I guess the problem is, by just looking at the base `IInterface`, I can't know that one of the children needs to be disposed. If this is the case, is it best practice to bubble up `IDisposable` whenever it will be grouped like that?

Comment: First, I don't think it is good practice to  implement `IDisposable` where it is not needed just to avail oneself ease of programming.
Instead you can get a collection of those that implement `IDisposable` by calling `listOfBaseInterface.OfType<IDisposable>()` outside the foreach block to get all the types that implement this separately and then you do the needful. Seems a cleaner way to go.